# Li:active doesn't work in my code

Tags: css, hyperlink, html-lists

I'm having trouble letting the background color and the font changed when the link is active (li:active doesn't work) Please help me guys.

**follow the link:** http://jsfiddle.net/rbL7ncf2/2/

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="menu"> 
    <ul>
        <li style="background-color:#5b90bf; color:#fff; font-weight:bold;">Produtos</li>
        <li><span class="button"  data-type="pdt1">Teste 1</span></li>
        <li><span class="button" data-type="pdt2">Teste 2</span></li>
        <li><span class="button" data-type="pdt3">Teste 3</span></li>
        <li><span class="button" data-type="pdt4">Teste 4</span></li>
        <li><span class="button" data-type="pdt5">Teste 5</span></li>
        <li><span class="button"  data-type="pdt6">Teste 6</span></li>
        <li><span class="button" data-type="pdt7">Teste 7</span></li>
        <li><span class="button" data-type="pdt8">Teste 8</span></li>
        <li><span class="button" data-type="pdt9">Teste 9</span></li>
        <li><span class="button" data-type="pdt10">Teste 10</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="boxes">        
    <div class="box" id="pdt1">classe 1</div>
    <div class="box" id="pdt2">classe 2</div>
    <div class="box" id="pdt3">classe 3</div>
    <div class="box" id="pdt4">classe 1</div>
    <div class="box" id="pdt5">classe 5</div>
    <div class="box" id="pdt6">classe 6</div>
    <div class="box" id="pdt7">classe 7</div>
    <div class="box" id="pdt8">classe 8</div>
    <div class="box" id="pdt9">classe 9</div>
    <div class="box" id="pdt10">classe 10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no `li:active` within you provided demo.

Comment: Can you specify what you are expecting to happen when you use `:active`, and what result you see? When I try this in Firefox, IE and Chrome it works, but they handle it a bit different. Firefox and Chrome will trigger `li:active` when you click on the `span` inside it, but IE only triggers it when you click on the `li`, not the `span` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Some Browser do no support :active selector except on link element (a) like IE7

Please elaborate on what browser you don't see it working?

Thanks

also as mentioned by other User, you fiddle missing the :active css!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use: (http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/rbL7ncf2/6/)

```
   $('ul li').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).closest("li").addClass('selected');
```

Whole js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.button').click(function(){
         $('ul li').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).closest("li").addClass('selected');
        var type = $(this).data('type');
        $('.boxes div').hide();      
        $('#' + type).fadeIn("slow");
    });    
});
```

Added css:

```
#menu ul li.selected:hover {
    background-color: #5b90bf;
    color:#303030;
}
.selected{
    color:#303030;
    background-color: #5b90bf;
}
```